# Mysqldump to dump specific table without using ignore-table

Tags: mysql

I want to dump certain tables with mysqldump.
The only way I found is run with a config.cnf file with [ignore-table] option to do that.

```
mysqldump --defaults-file="./config.cnf" "main" > ./main.sql
```

**config.cnf:**

```
[mysqldump]
ignore-table=main.TableNoNeedToDump1
ignore-table=main.TableNoNeedToDump2
ignore-table=main.TableNoNeedToDump3
...
ignore-table=main.TableNoNeedToDump1000
```

But what if I have too many tables and maybe some of them are auto generated but I dont need to dump them?

Is there any way to write .cnf to pick specific tables only?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the table names in the command:

```
mysqldump [connection params] databasename table1 table2 table3 > ./main.sql
```

Comment: I know it works in cli. But for some reason, can I use it in cnf file?